# Page Layout with Fixed HTML Header and Footer, with Flexible content

Tags: html, css

I have a web page (HTML+CSS) with a header and footer fixed.

I want a Content-div between the headers and footers that is "flexible" when the browser window (document) is resized.

If the Content-div is too small to display its content, the Content-div must display horizontal and vertical scrollbars - Not the browser window.
If the Content-div is too big to display its content the, Content-div must not display horizontal and vertical scrollbars - Not the browser window.

In short, the Content-div must automatically handle the resizing of the browser, between the header and footers.

My Current code probably just needs some tweaking in the CSS to get this right.

I Currently hardcode the height of the Content-div to force a scrollbar (100px), but this should work automatically.

Should I maybe look at using JavaScript to accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

<style>

    #header, #footer {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:200;
        height:100px;
        background-color:brown;

        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1;                

    }

    #header {
        top:0;
    }

    #footer {
        bottom:0;
    }
    #main-content {

        overflow:scroll;

        height:100px; 

        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:130px 0;  

        border-style:dashed;
        border-width:1;                                  
    }

    #navigation, #paging {
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

</style>


    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body >

<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">Navigation goes here</div>
</div>

<div id="main-content" > Section content goes here
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>

Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>
Section content goes here<br>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="paging">Paging controls go here</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with a little help of jQuery if you're interested, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/KA3qq/)**</kbd>

```
#main-content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

```
<script>
  (function($) {
     $('#main-content').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 200 + 'px' });
     $(window).resize(function() {
       $('#main-content').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 200 + 'px' });
     });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```